# Nowhere vanishing section on the Mobius strip

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

This is similar to another question asked on here, but the answers there didn't help me (and it is a slightly different set-up).

Consider the vector bundle $$E := ([0,1]\times \Bbb{R})/\sim \to S^1$$ where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation that says $(0,t) \sim (1,-t)$ for all $t \in \Bbb{R}$. Does there exist a nowhere vanishing section of $E$?

---

---

I know the answer is "no", and I have tried to follow the answers given on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2377515/showing-that-every-smooth-section-of-the-mobius-strip-vanishes-somewhere) post, but I don't understand how they conclude the section $s$ must have a zero, just because $F$ does (notation from the linked post).

Could someone explain this in full? Because I really lack understanding of differential geometry to be able to 'fill in gaps' in proofs like this if I'm not familiar with them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no differential geometry here. All that is required is the intermediate value theorem. Think of a section as a continuous map from $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb R$. To be well-defined as a section of $E$, how does the equivalence relation require $F(0)$ and $F(1)$ be related?

Comment: So I assume you define $S^1 = [0,1]/\sim$ where $0 \sim 1$. Then if we write $s:S^1\to E: s([x]) = [(x,F(x))]$, we must have $F(0) = -F(1)$, so $F$ must be zero somewhere. But how does that say $s$ has a zero? Is $[(x,0)]$ the zero vector in $\pi^{-1}(x)$? (Here $\pi$ is the vector bundle)

Comment: Yes, precisely. The zero section is the map $x\mapsto[(x,0)]$.